# What's the meaning of "block is entered recursively"?

Tags: c, scope, language-lawyer, storage-duration

I asked a question on reddit. The question was literally [Why does the starting point of a lifetime of an automatic object(which doesn't have VLA) precede a scope of an object?](https://www.reddit.com/r/C_Programming/comments/jwx8u0/why_the_starting_point_of_a_lifetime_of_an/)

And I got the answer which can be the example of my question.

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0;
back:
    printf("i = %d", i);
    int j;
    if (i < 5) {
        if (i == 0)
            j = 0;
        j += i;
        printf(", j = %d\n", j);
        i++;
        goto back;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**Output**

```
i = 0, j = 0
i = 1, j = 1
i = 2, j = 3
i = 3, j = 6
i = 4, j = 10
i = 5
```

But someone said "The value of `j` becomes indeterminate when its declaration is reached, ..." because of C17 6.2.4p6(with my bold)

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry
> into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an
> enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end, execution of the current block.) **If
> the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time.** The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration or compound literal is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.

Just going to a label in current block differs from repeating an entire associated block in a recursive function or an iterative statement. In this point of view, I don't think `j` is not affected by the rule(but it's just my thought).
By the way, I think there is a contradiction irrespective of which way we think. 
- If `int j;` isn't created anew in each sequence, it is a redefinition. 
 - If `int j;` is created anew in each sequence, `j` shall have a garbage value from second sequence. But the output is shown as if the value of 'j' is retained.
I read quoted part of documentation over and over, but couldn't understand it. What am I missing?

Comment: `goto` is not recursion, the part about recursion does not apply here.

Comment: @EOF but a code like `{ back: { /* ... */ goto back; } }` could be the example of the quotation because the inner block is entered recursively. Isn't it?

Comment: More repeatedly than recursively

Comment: Ok, `int j` isn't created anew in each sequence. Then it leads `j` is redefined in each sequence. Isn't there any grammatical error?

Comment: Are you just curious? Because there's never a good reason to use goto for loops like this.

Comment: And how do you know it isn't garbage values? A common garbage value is "whatever was there before"

Comment: I essentially am not curious about what I asked just before, but, if the code is not complete itself, that means I didn't get the answer about the first question on reddit.

Comment: Re “If int j; isn't created anew in each sequence, it is a redefinition”: No, declarations are not code that is executed like statements. If a declaration exists at a point in the code, it tells the compiler something about the identifier there. It does not mean the compiler generates code that “defines” the object each time program execution reaches the point where the declaration appears. Declarations may have some aspects that result in executable code, such as initialization of automatic objects, and the compiler will generate code for that…

Comment: … But it does not mean the declaration is a redefinition each time execution reaches it.

Comment: @klutt I first though like your comment. `A common garbage value is "whatever was there before` I interpret the bold sentence "a new instance of the object" as "new memory space is allocated and a garbage value is in there"

Comment: I don't think it's even applicable in your case, but even if it was, with your code the new object will most likely be created in the exact same memory as the old.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with your comment but I also have an opposite thought. `{ int a; printf("%x", &a); }` This means `int a;` cause a storage for `a`. So `int a` is a definition(you must already know). But I can't understand `int a;` becomes a declaration from second sequence.

Comment: Definition is a declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part that is important is later:

> If an initialization is specified for the object, [...]; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate **each time** the declaration is reached.

Each time `int j` is reached, the value of `j` becomes indeterminate. `j` retaining the previous value is also an example of garbage value, as that can be *any* value. If your code depends on that value, that means the behavior of your code is not defined.

> If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time

A "block" is generally something that starts with a `{` and ends with a `}`. That paragraph is for recursive function.

```
void func()
{ // block start
    int a; // new instance of object created each time, even recursively
    func(); // enter the block recursively
} // block end
```

There is one block in your code created with `int main(void) {` and another block in your code is the one after `if (i < 5) {`. *That `if (i < 5) {` block* is not entered recursively, it's entered, then leaved, then entered again, then leaved again.

> If int j; isn't created anew in each sequence, it is a redefinition.

Quoting that quote:

> For such an object [object with automatic storage duration, see previous point in standard] that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends **from entry into the block** with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

The lifetime of the object identified by `j` starts at entry into the block, so I would argue it's not "created anew".

```
int main(void) { // lifetime of "object j" starts here
                 // but you can't access it, no identifier is associated with it
back:;
    int j; // the identifier `j` is associated with "object j"
           // the value of the object associated with `j` is indeterminate
           // _each time_ execution flow gets here
    goto back;
} // lifetime of "object j" ends here (or at `return`)
  // scope of identifier `j` also ends here
```

Comment: In your first quote, "otherwise" is the same as "If the block is entered recursively and If an initialization is **not** specified for the object" You denied that "If the block is entered recursively"(I agree with this point and your explanation `it's entered, then leaved, then entered again` was easy to understand). Then you can't explain the value of `int j` with the first quote.

Comment: "otherwise", as in when the initialization is not specified for the object. The block is not entered recursively. If the block would be entered recursively, then yes. I do not understand `Then you can't explain the value of int j with the first quote`? The behavior of your program is undefined - [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) can spawn. There is no explanation for any behavior of code that is undefined, because... it's undefined.

Comment: "as in when the initialization is not specified for the object", this is applicable when the prior sentence "If the block is entered recursively" is true. Isn't it? `If A { if A-1 else A-2}` A = "If the block is entered recursively"

Comment: I do not follow, it's not `if A { ...}` it's `if that, do that. If that, do that.` It's a list of unrelated conditions. The function may or may be not entered recursively - the last sentence applies no matter. There's a full stop between sentences.

Comment: When comparing to below paragraph(6.2.4p7), I recognized you were right. I apologize for unnecessary argument. And thanks that one becomes clear. Now I agree with the `int j` is the circumstance `otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.` One point is left, the problem is `int j` is declared more than once. You agreed with Eric's comment and said "Definition is a declaration". But this is not explained with your and Eric's comment. `int main(){ int a=1; int a;}` My gcc doesn't allow this. Why is the second declaration `int a` not a declaration of first?

Comment: `the problem is int j is declared more than once` No, it isn't. There is one `int j` inside `{` `}` the block. Each time _the execution flow encounters_ the declaration, something happens. Still there is one declaration. As for "definition is declaration", [C11 6.7p5](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5) should be clear enough. Definition is a declaration that reserves storage. `Why is the second declaration int a not a declaration of first?` It falls into [6.7p3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p3).